# What is an algebraic scheme?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

In Sernesi's book "Deformations of Algebraic Schemes", on page 2 ("Terminology and Notation"), he defines "(schemes)" to be the category of locally noetherian separated $k$-schemes, where $k$ is a fixed alg. closed field.

Then he writes "(algschemes) = the category of algebraic schemes", but does not explain what the adjective "algebraic" means.

What does this mean?

I suspect it might mean "finite type over $k$", but I've never heard of this terminology before so hopefully someone here might be able to confirm this.

Comment: [[EGAI](http://www.numdam.org/item?id=PMIHES_1960__4__5_0), Def. 6.4.1] defines an algebraic scheme as a scheme that is of finite type over $\operatorname{Spec} k$. This matches the [Stacks Project](http://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/06LF), and so this is most likely what Sernesi means.